# Printing the full HTML of the DOM element that triggered an eventListener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print out the full HTML of the DOM element with limited success. I would like to know if there's a helper in JavaScript that's intended to do just that.

```
this.div.click( function(e) {
    alert(e.target);
    alert(e.target.tagName);
    alert(JSON.stringify($(e.target).parent()));
});
```

I am expecting to get something like:

```
<div class="gameActivator AnyItem-Off-selector UI-Widget UI-Content"><span class="content widget-inner"><button class="activateButton"></button></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to get the element on which the event listener was originally attached. Then you can read all the HTML of that element with [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

```
this.div.click( function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.outerHTML);
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdk9k9a8/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), depending on wether you want to include the given element in the returned HTML.

```
this.div.click( function(e) {

    console.log( this.innerHTML );
    console.log( this.outerHTML );

});
```

In jQuery it would be just [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
console.log( $(this).html() );
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the innerHTML of the parent div? I tried using alert($(e.target).parent().innerHTML);, but I get undefined. Thanks, for the help.

Comment: @henry - You're sure you don't want `this` instead of `event.target`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.outerHTML`. Inside a jQuery event handler `this` is the current element

```
this.div.click( function(e) {
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```